# How to vary a stateful variable in a react hook on each re-render?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to animate a complex react component. Take as given please that this animation cannot be accomplished with css. This component has a stateful variable `x` such that a re-render is triggered on each update of `x`. I want to be able to vary `x` from its current value to a target value with smooth re-renderings of the component as a consequence. Here is a schematic of my first naive attempt to do this:

```
export const MyComponent = (props: IProps) => {

  // Trigger 'animation' by toggling this boolean
  const [isXzero, setIsXzero] = useState(true);

  // I want x to vary between 0 and 500
  const [x, setX] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isXzero && x < 500) setX(x + 1);
    if (!!isXzero && x > 0) setX(x - 1);
  }, [isXzero, x]);

  return (<>...</>);
}
```

This "works" but results in the following warning:

> Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a
>   component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either
>   doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on
>   every render.

I'm pretty sure that this is suffering from the "one of the dependencies changes on every render" anti-pattern. Is there a sensible React-ish way to do what I'm trying to achieve (a relatively smooth re-rendering as I vary `x` between target values)?

Comment: Is there ever a state where the animation finishes? How often do you wish the animation to run?

Comment: The animation starts/stops when x gets to its target value (0 and 500 in example above). Toggling the boolean `isXzero` achieves this in the logic above, but with the warning for rookies. I want the animation to run whenever I toggle the boolean `isXzero`.

Comment: React internally gives you a warning if you trigger more than 50state updates within a specified frame of time which in your case it does happen. To trigger complex animation you can try to use keyFrames with css. Maybe this link help you https://css-tricks.com/using-multi-step-animations-transitions/

Comment: Thanks for feedback. My conclusion is: don't animate this way. (I'll have to do some complex css-svg interplay instead :(

Comment: I think you can avoid the warning if you use `requestAnimationFrame`. https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe-with-react-hooks/